# Notepad++ deleting tags with specific text inside

Tags: php, regex, xml, notepad++

I have a large XML file with products inside. I'm trying to delete all products which are out of stock. File size is over 20MB.

```
<product>
  <name>bla1</name>
  <price>50$</price>
  <stock>yes</stock>
  <description>bla</description>
</product>

<product>
  <name>bla2</name>
  <price>60$</price>
  <stock>no</stock>
  <description>bla</description>
</product>

...
```

Is it possible to delete them using Notepad++'s regex or should I use simpleXML(PHP) or something similar?

My basic PHP code:

```
$url = 'input/products.xml';
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($url));

    foreach ($xml->product->children() as $product) {

        //finding out of stock products and deleting them

    }
    $xml->asXml('output/products.xml');
```

Comment: Does every `product` have a `stock` element?

Comment: The file has over 30k+ lines but to my best knowledge, yes. Every product has a stock element with various text inside. (in stock, out of stock, new stock incoming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Forward

Doing pattern matching via regular expression is not ideal, if you have access to PHP, then I recommend using a proper HTLM parsing tool. With that said, I offer a solution you can use in Notepad++

## Description

`<product\s*(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\s?\/?>(?:(?!</product).)*<stock\s*(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\s?\/?>no</stock>(?:(?!</product).)*<\/product>`

**Replace with:**  nothing

[image: Regular expression visualization]

To view the image better, you can right click it and select view in new window.

This Regular Expression will do the following:

- find the entire product section
- require the subtag `stock`
- require the subtag `stock` to have a value of `no`
- avoid extremely edge cases that makes pattern matching in HTML difficult

## From Notepad ++

From Notepad++, note that you should be using notpad++ version 6.1 or later as there were problems with regular expressions in an older version that have been solved now.

1. press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> to enter the find and replace
   mode
2. Select the Regular Expression option
3. In the "Find what" field place the regular expression
4. in the "Replace with" field enter ``
5. Click <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/cW9nC5/1

**Sample text**

```
<product>
  <name>bla1</name>
  <price>50$</price>
  <stock>yes</stock>
  <description>bla</description>
</product>

<product>
  <name>bla2</name>
  <price>60$</price>
  <stock>no</stock>
  <description>bla</description>
</product>
```

**After Replace**

```
<product>
  <name>bla1</name>
  <price>50$</price>
  <stock>yes</stock>
  <description>bla</description>
</product>
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  <product                 '<product'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ='                       '=\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ="                       '="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^'"]                    any character except: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\s>]*                  any character except: whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " "), '>' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                           (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/?                      '/' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>\r\n'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      </product                '</product'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  <stock                   '<stock'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ='                       '=\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ="                       '="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^'"]                    any character except: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\s>]*                  any character except: whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " "), '>' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                           (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/?                      '/' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  >no</stock>              '>no</stock>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      </product                '</product'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  product>                 'product>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, works like a charm. I'm just in a process of writing PHP script which will handle multiple XML files from suppliers and integrate them in a single CSV file but until then, I'm forced to manually edit XML to fit in our shop.

Answer (score 1):

I guess notepad++ will be easier, i.e.:

<kbd>FIND :</kbd> `<product>\s+<name>.*?<\/name>\s+<price>.*?<\/price>\s+<stock>no<\/stock>\s+<description>.*?\/description>\s+<\/product>`
<kbd>REPLACE :</kbd> with nothing

---

**DEMO**

https://regex101.com/r/fH0mM7/1

---

**NOTE**

Make sure you check`Regular Expression` at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with PHP using the below code

```
<?php
    $url = 'input/products.xml';
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($url));
    $i = count($xml) - 1; 
    for ($i; $i >= 0; --$i) {   
       $product = $xml->product[$i];
       if ($product->stock == "no") {
          unset($xml->product[$i]);
       }
    }
    $xml->asXml('output/products.xml');
    ?>
```

Comment: I already solved the problem with @RoYoMi answer, but I'll definitely need your answer for PHP script I'm working on so thanks.